# How to convert ASCII to hexdecimal in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, hex

I want to make a program that converts an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) string to hexadecimal in VB.NET.

This is what I'm talking about:

There is a form with two textboxes and one button. The user puts in something in ASCII in textbox1, and after hitting the button, textbox2 displays it in hexadecimal.

So input in ASCII on textbox 1: test

Output in hexadecimal in textbox2 after hitting button1: 74657374

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What would make the user believe that only characters in the ASCII range would be allowed? .NET strings (and therefore the .Text property) use Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that convert **string to hex value**

```
Dim str As String = "test"
Dim byteArray() As Byte
Dim hexNumbers As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
byteArray = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)
For i As Integer = 0 To byteArray.Length - 1
    hexNumbers.Append(byteArray(i).ToString("x"))
Next
MsgBox(hexNumbers.ToString()) ' Out  put will be 74657374
```

The following code will reverse the operation and verify the output:

```
Dim st As String = hexNumbers.ToString
Dim com As String = ""
For x = 0 To st.Length - 1 Step 2
    com &= ChrW(CInt("&H" & st.Substring(x, 2)))
Next
MsgBox(com)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox2.Text = ""
For Each c As Char In textbox1.Text
    textbox2.Text &= Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16)
Next
```